# What is the file path of account.aged.payable model and how to edit aged payable report?

Tags: python, odoo-14

I want to edit the aged payable xlsx report in Accounting->Report->Aged payable odoo14. However, I am not getting the report template in the odoo sh staging branch editor console. Where can I find the model and the template in the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of reports are one of the technical implementations in Odoo. These reports are implemented via sql queries based in functions.

You can find their implementation in **enterprise** **>** **account_reports** **>** **models.**

In **models** folder, multiple files have respective report implementations like partner ledger, aged receivable and payable.

Comment: since it is not in addons folder is it possible to override methods by creating a custom module?

Comment: yes, no difference with customization strategies whether it is in `addons` or `enterprise`.

Comment: can you give any hint about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219669/adding-multiple-records-to-one2many-tree-in-form-view-in-odoo-10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110760/is-it-possible-to-have-serial-numbers-to-the-lot-items-in-odoo14