# Is it possible to have serial numbers to the lot items in odoo14?

Tags: python, odoo-14

In odoo I can work with either lots or unique serial number. But I want to unique serial number to each and every items in a single lot. Then I will transfer that lot. So, is it possible to add serial number to the lot item?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I solved this problem a while ago on odoo-12 using a customized code [ to ensure that the serial number is unique to each lot]

Comment: did you create new model and made relation? E.g: lot_model one2many examplemodel. If yes, can you give any hint with the model _name?